# I have the strangest display bug on Lubuntu 16.10. Can someone help me fix it? Screenshot and details attached

Tags: nvidia, lubuntu, 16.10, lxde

[image]

That's the screenshot. Notice how the decorations around tabs and buttons aren't appearing on most windows. But chrome and "customize look and feel" (lxappearance, I think) and steam work fine.

I think a major part of the problem is that I did a lubuntu minimal installation from the mini.iso (if IIRC, it installs lubuntu-core) and then built on that. I might have missed some packages that I might have needed... Everything else works as it should. I haven't messed around with nvidia driver settings beyond installing them and setting resolutions.

```
Lubuntu 16.10
Core i5-6402p
20GB RAM (Yes, 16+4)
2xSSD+HDD (root, /home and storage)
Nvidia GTX 1060 6GB
```

Thanks in advance!

PS. I would prefer not to reinstall my OS/desktop over a small display bug. There must be a way to fix it without doing either of those.

Comment: How do things look if you use `Adwaita` as the widget theme?

Comment: @DKBose I figured it out just as you posted. Yup, the theme lubuntu-dark-panel was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out. It was really dumb on my part to not double check the theme I was using. I figured it out after I deleted the GTK section from /home/sisir/.config/lxsession/LXDE/desktop.conf and logged back it.

Turns out lubuntu-dark-panel theme is broken and that was causing my problems. Really odd since it's a theme supplied by the Lubuntu folks, but whatever, it's fixed and life is happy again

Comment: I don't think lubuntu-dark-panel is broken, at least in Lubuntu 16.04 where it's working just fine. It's possible you're missing some component. My bet is it's `gtk3-engines-unico`. Install that and then try lubuntu-dark-panel again.